# Find the number of $m$-digit numbers whose sum of digits is $12$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is straight forward. Here is my attempt but I am not sure if it is correct.

$$x_1+x_2+...+x_m=12 \; \ldots(1), \quad x_1\ge1, \quad 0\le x_i \le9$$

Number of total solutions is $\binom{m+10}{11}$

$A_i$ - set of numbers where $x_i\ge 10$;
$|A_i|=\binom{m+1}{2}$

Final result: $\binom{m+10}{11} - m\binom{m+1}{2}$

So to sum it all up, I calculated number of total solution of the equation $(1)$, and subtracted the number of solutions if $x_i\ge10$.

Edit: I have taken into account the $x_1\ge1$ term. This is what I get now, but I'm still missing something

Comment: Is the word "over" meant to be read as "choose"?

Comment: dont forget that the first term must be $x_1>0$,as well

Comment: It's meant to be "choose", sorry for my bad terminology.

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish That might be a problem, will check right now

Comment: I made a small change, I believe it is ok now. @NotaSalmonFish may like to see.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We wish to find the number of $m$-digit numbers with digit sum $12$.  If $x_i$ represents the $i$th digit, then we wish to find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m = 12 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_i \leq 9$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$.

To handle the first constraint, let $x_1' = x_1 - 1$.  Then $x_1'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 1$ for $x_1$ in equation $1$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m & = 12\\
x_1' + x_2 + \cdots + x_m & = 11 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation $2$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers subject to the constraints $x_1' \leq 8$, $x_i \leq 9$ for $2 \leq i \leq m$.

If we initially ignore the upper bounds in equation $2$, then equation $2$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{11 + m - 1}{m - 1} = \binom{m + 10}{m - 1} = \binom{m + 10}{11}$$
solutions by [Theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two)) on the linked page.

Thus far, we agree.  However, you did not take into account the restriction that $x_1' \leq 8$.

Suppose $x_1' \geq 9$.  Then $x_1'' = x_1 - 9$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1'' + 9$ for $x_1'$ in Equation $2$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_1'' + 9 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m & = 11\\
x_1'' + x_2 + \cdots + x_m & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation $3$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{2 + m - 1}{m - 1} = \binom{m + 1}{m - 1} = \binom{m + 1}{2}$$
solutions.

Suppose one of the remaining $m - 1$ variables is at least $10$.  For instance, suppose $x_2 \geq 10$.  Then $x_2' = x_2 - 10$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_2' + 10$ for $x_2$ in Equation $2$ yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + x_2' + 10 + x_3 + \cdots + x_m & = 11\\
x_1' + x_2' + x_3 + \cdots + x_m & = 1 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation $4$ is an equation in the nonnegative integers with
$$\binom{1 + m - 1}{m - 1} = \binom{m}{m - 1} = \binom{m}{1} = m$$
solutions.  Hence, there are $m(m - 1)$ solutions of equation $2$ that violate one of the restrictions $x_i \leq 9$ for $2 \leq i \leq m$.

Therefore, the number of $m$-digit numbers with digit sum $12$ is
$$\binom{m + 10}{m - 1} - \binom{m + 1}{m - 1} - m(m - 1)$$

Comment: classic is classic $+1$

Comment: Indeed classic (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach, which basically computes first for a "solid" number without zeroes, and then adds zeroes to fill the gap to $m$ digits

Cases for $m=2,3$ are trivial, hardly worth the trouble of using stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion, "solid" numbers easily counted by hand for $m=2,3$, as $7,52 $

The good thing is that for $m=4$ onwards, it is impossible to have more than $9$ for any cell, so all numbers will be solid

For required  minimum of $4$ solid digits, eg $1119, 1128$
etc can be computed by [stars and bars Th 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in $\Large\binom{11}3$ ways

Balance $(m-4)\,0's$ can be filled in $4$ "boxes" using stars and bars Th $2$  in $\Large\binom{m-4\;+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{m-1}3$ ways

The formula that thus emerges  $m>=12,4\le k \le 12$, is

$$ \sum_{k=4}^{12}\binom{11}{k-1}\binom{m-1}{k-1}$$

plus $\Large\binom{m-1}1+\Large\binom{m-1}2$ for $2,3$ digit solid numbers

Comment: $+1$ for this interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, for $m=2$ you would get ${13 \choose 12} - 2 {2 \choose 2} = 11$, but there are actually $7$ such $2$-digit numbers, namely $39$, $48$, $57$, $66$, $75$, $84$, $93$.

You need to subtract the solutions (i.e. $m$-tuples of natural numbers adding to $12$) with a $12$ and $m-1$ $0$'s; an $11$, a $1$ and $m-2$ $0$'s; a $10$, a $2$, and $m-2$ $0$'s; or a $10$, two $1$'s, and $m-3$ $0$'s.  If $f(m)$ is the number of solutions remaining, that's still not your answer, because it  allows leading $0$'s: you'll want to take $f(m) - f(m-1)$.